# Sum of absolute values of solutions of $(2 + \sqrt 3)^x + (2 - \sqrt 3)^x=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, radicals, transcendental-equations

What is the sum of the absolute values of all the $x$-s that satisfy the equation:$$(2 + \sqrt 3)^x + (2 - \sqrt 3)^x=4$$

Comment: Observe that $\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})}=2+\sqrt{3}$. Call $y=(2+\sqrt{3})^x$ and the equation becomes $y+\frac{1}{y}=4$, or $y^2-4y+1=0$. Once you solve for $y=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{12}}{2}$ then $x=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}$. Mind the fact that $y$ should be positive.

Comment: You've been on this site long enough to know that you're expected to show your own workings while posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $2-\sqrt{3}= \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let  $f(x)=(2 + \sqrt 3)^x + (2 - \sqrt 3)^x-4$. Now show that $f$ decreases for negative $x$ and increases for positive $x$.

Obviously $1$ is a zero of $f$. Then from the symmetry of $f$, namely $f(-x)=f(x)$, it follows that $-1$ is the only other zero of $f$, so their absolute values sum up to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(2+\sqrt3)^x=t$.

Hence, we need $t+\frac{1}{t}=4$, which gives $t=2+\sqrt3$ or $t=2-\sqrt3$ and we get the answer:
$$\{1,-1\}.$$